# "Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found" on fatjar with sbt assembly

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-flink

I'm building a job in Scala to run on a Flink Cluster, that will store data in AWS S3, and I've some problems related to dependencies.

I've checked most of the question previously asked here, and to fix this I needed to add `flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.9.1.jar` jar files to the `$FLINK_HOME/plugins` in order to run my job successfully:

My question is, should this be detected as been inside the fatjar generate by `sbt assembly` ? The files are inside the jar, but for some reason the Flink Cluster can't see them.

I know that in the documentation says that `flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.9.1.jar` should download to `$FLINK_HOME/plugins` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Filesystems cannot be bundled in the user-jar, they **must** be present either in /lib or /plugins.
The components that use filesystems aren't necessarily aware of the user-jar.